# Allocating a char buffer with JNA, Rhino, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rhino, jna, libc, commonjs

In Narwhal, we are using JNA to make `libc` calls like `getcwd` and `chdir`.  I've only been able to use this with my limited knowledge of the JNA interface as it pertains to JavaScript in Rhino, dealing exclusively with primitives.  I need to know how to allocate a char buffer so I can pass it to `getcwd`, retrieve a JavaScript String from that buffer, and deallocate the buffer, presumably in a `finally` clause.

Here's how we grab the `libc` interface:

http://github.com/280north/narwhal/blob/34ac15261fa4acdef3867256e97d7aabb94766e0/engines/rhino/lib/fs-base.js#L32-42

Here's how `chdir` is implemented:

http://github.com/280north/narwhal/blob/34ac15261fa4acdef3867256e97d7aabb94766e0/engines/rhino/lib/fs-base.js#L438-444

Here's where we need the solution for `getcwd`

http://github.com/280north/narwhal/blob/34ac15261fa4acdef3867256e97d7aabb94766e0/engines/rhino/lib/fs-base.js#L416-419

Solutions in Ruby or any other embedded language for JNA would help.

Comment: Got a hint from @binary42 regarding JRuby http://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/src/org/jruby/RubyDir.java#L374 still parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an nio.Buffer or jna.Pointer to pass an output buffer, something like:

```
invokeString(new jna.Memory(4097), 4097)
```

getcwd will return a char* to the input buffer, so jna will marshall the return to a string

to support longer paths, you could take an optional length

in java, new File(".").getAbsolutePath() can get the current path, so you might not need getcwd...

Comment: Solution: http://github.com/kriskowal/narwhal/blob/3d6a7cd99c086340f695255057e93e877ed482d1/engines/rhino/lib/fs-base.js#L477-486